# Azure Mobile Services - System.PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm working on a xamarin forms app with azure however when I load my initial page it crashes on the line:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService =
               new MobileServiceClient(
               "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net");
```

with exception:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException "The empty PCL implementation for
>   Microsoft Azure Mobile Services was loaded. Ensure you have added
>   nuget package to each of your platform projects."

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you add the nuget package to the android, ios, and uwp app if included?

Comment: @KenTucker I have the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client in all parts of the app if that's what you mean.

Comment: yes it is.  What platforms is the xamarin forms app supporting?

Comment: @KenTucker iOS and Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might mean that the NuGet packages did not install correctly in one of your platforms. I would suggest doing a [force-reinstall of all NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) using the `Package Manager Console` (`Tools/NuGet Package Manager/Package Manager Console`).

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

Do this for all projects in your solution. Once done, close and reopen Visual Studio, open your solution and click `Build` in the top menu and do `Clean Solution`.

Now look into each of your platform projects in turn to see if you have a `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` reference there:

[image: NuGet reference]

If it is not there, install the `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` package again in that given project.

Then you should proceed as described in any tutorial on Azure Mobile Services. Even if you use the Shared Project strategy in you Xamarin.Forms app, it should work as expected once the platform project has `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` installed.

If it does not help, as the last resort I would suggest trying to update all NuGet packages to their last version (right-click solution, Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...)

Comment: I'm using visual studio for mac where there is no package manager console, so how would I go about reinstalling them

Comment: Oh, I haven't thought about that possiblity. In that case try installing the  MonoDevelop NuGet addin https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions . It contains the console which should be able to perform the requested commands

Comment: Sorry how exactly do I install this

Comment: It should be possible going by the Installation guide - https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions#installation

Comment: it should be in Visual Studio menu > Extensions

Comment: Right ok, got it, when I open the console now it doesn't allow me to input anything and the package source, default project, etc. dropdown at the top of the console are greyed out.

Comment: That is very weird... Ok, let's first try to uninstall the package normally (delete from Packages from the project) and the install it again from NuGet. That itself might help.

Comment: I removed the azure package and then installed it again like you said now i'm getting System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000016 (from typeref, class/assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform, Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)

Comment: It seems that this error sometimes happens when there are some leftovers in the `bin` and `obj` folders. Please close Visual Studio and delete `bin` and `obj` folders in the your project folders (Android, iOS, ...)

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad! Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you add the initialization code in the respective AppDelegate/MainActivity

```
CurrentPlatform.Init();
```

And that in the iOS, Android and **PCL** projects there is the reference to the `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client` package.

[Example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices/TodoAzure)

It instantiates the MobileServiceClient in the TodoItemManager class.

Comment: I don't have a pcl

Comment: SCL? Where is placed the code throwing the exception?

Comment: When initiating my first page on the line where noted in my question

Comment: The Init call should be in the AppDelegate/MainActivity while you should instantiate the MobileServiceClient in the PCL/SCL project in one of the first calls. I've added to the answer the link to the official Xamarin.Forms example

Comment: Yeah sorry i said that wrong when talking about initiation im talking about where i declare my apps main page sorry i should have been clearer the init is already in app delegate and mainactivity